# Nested c:choose tags not working

Tags: java, jsp

I'm working on a jsp page which has the following code;

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${profile.blocked != '1'">

   <div>Message Me</div>

<c:choose>
<c:when test="${profile.favourite == '0'}">
  <div>Add Favourite</div>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
  <div>Remove Favourite</div>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<c:choose>
<c:when test="${profile.intimate == '0'}">
  <div>Add Friend</div>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
  <div>Remove Friend</div>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</c:when>

<c:otherwise>
   <div>Profile Blocked</div>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

The problem is that the Profile Blocked message is not displaying when a profile is blocked. I know the underlying code is ok so it must be something in my front end code.

Comment: Indenting your xml would help with readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `}` from your `when` tag:

```
<c:when test="${profile.blocked != '1'">
```

should be

```
<c:when test="${profile.blocked != '1'}">
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Will mark as the correct answer as soon I'm able to.